# jQuery Animate top: Does not work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

Ok so I really cant figure out why this code is not working. Works fine in other browsers but in Chrome the bar does not scroll.

I have a toolbar I want to scroll up and down the page. This works in other browsers but not Chrome:

```
$("#toolbar").stop().animate({top: 100}, 1000);
```

It really does not make any sense to me... Here is the CSS:

```
#toolbar{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:0px;
z-index:9999;
width:100%;}
```

Currently the only think in the div is text can anyone help!?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 11.0.696.28. Did you forget to enclose the code in `$(document).ready` maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/hans/MtaWq/

Answer (score 0):

Use `stop` with arguments, for instance `stop(true,false)`.
This should fix the behavior in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#toolbar").stop().animate({top: '100px'}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of top, use `{"padding-top":"+=15px"}` to be relative